# How to build an AI system which learns from corpus and answers to the user whenever they ask anything related to that corpus

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I am planning to build an AI system that learns from the corpus (text file) and needs to answer to question for user like chatbot to be short chatbot without any predefined data.

Until now I webscraped some data and stored as a text file and I used TF-IDF(cosine similarity) method to make the system to answer questions  but the accuracy level is moderate only

```py
def response(user_response):
    robo_response=''
    sent_tokens.append(user_response)
    TfidfVec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=LemNormalize, stop_words='english')
    tfidf = TfidfVec.fit_transform(sent_tokens)
    vals = cosine_similarity(tfidf[-1], tfidf)
    idx=vals.argsort()[0][-2]
    flat = vals.flatten()
    flat.sort()
    req_tfidf = flat[-2]
    if(req_tfidf==0):    
        robo_response=robo_response+"cant understand"
        return robo_response
    else:
        robo_response = robo_response+sent_tokens[idx]
        return robo_response
```

TD-IDF method which I used

Is there any other way to build a system to do the work somewhat accurately?

Comment: i am completely in the amateur level so pls help me to do complete this project

Comment: Have a look at BERT: https://github.com/google-research/bert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFA links for something that you want to do.

https://demo.allennlp.org/reading-comprehension
https://towardsdatascience.com/elmo-contextual-language-embedding-335de2268604

They are already built systems that allow you to do just that.

If you want to build something similar from scratch, there are a lot of process that need to be followed on the processed text.

Tfidf is a BoW(bag of words) algorithm that can help you identify the intent, but not relation between those intents. The matrix that is obtained from vectorized tfidf along with the label will just tell the machine that if for some text, similar matrix is obtained, this is the label. Which is handy in classification, but not for chatbot responses.

To get response from chatbot:
-Segment text into sentences.
-use various techniques to obtain context of the text, currently XLNet is provided best results( https://medium.com/dair-ai/xlnet-outperforms-bert-on-several-nlp-tasks-9ec867bb563b ). This will help you to formulate responses to queries that can be asked via chatbot.
Above are few rudimentary steps, an actual AI system will involve a lot more.